# How to remove old branch HWE kernels?

Tags: kernel

today I ran the usual update on my ubuntu server version 20.04.whatever and I see this, as usual:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-58-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-57-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-57-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-56-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-56-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-137-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-137-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-136-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-136-generic
```

So, my system, due to newer HWE, has kernel version 5.15 but I still have installed (and updated but not used) kernel branch 5.4.
While update process works correcly, and autoremove correctly older version: can I get rid once for all kernel 5.4?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete output of `dpkg -l | grep linux | grep ii`

Answer (score 6):

You can use Synaptic and remove all `5.4` kernel image and headers.

This should also remove `linux-generic`, `linux-image-generic` and `linux-headers-generic` packages.

This will stop upgrading non-HWE kernels.